# How to dynamically add columns in PostgresSQL select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, grafana, supabase

I have this table:

```
+------+----+-------+
| Time | Id | Value |
+------+----+-------+
| 1    | 1  | 0     |
+------+----+-------+
| 2    | 1  | 10    |
+------+----+-------+
| 3    | 1  | 20    |
+------+----+-------+
| 1    | 2  | 0     |
+------+----+-------+
| 2    | 2  | -10   |
+------+----+-------+
| 3    | 2  | -20   |
+------+----+-------+
| 1    | 3  | 0     |
+------+----+-------+
| 2    | 3  | 0     |
+------+----+-------+
| 3    | 3  | 0     |
+------+----+-------+
```

I want to create an SQL select statement that would return me this table:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Time | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 0      | 0      | 0      |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2    | 10     | -10    | 0      |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 3    | 20     | -20    | 0      |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

- Q: Why I would not change my structure in the first place?
- A: The ID's are linked to IoT device details and they are added dynamically
  (meaning that customer will one day have 40 of devices working and other 70).

**What I want to achieve?**
The SQL statement should be working with the ID's dynamically (meaning that the number of returned columns will change based on how many different ID's there are).

**What I have tried?**
I have tried various SQL statements but my knowledge is fairly limited and I can't do it on my own ... Group by time gives me ID and Value column in only aggregate form.

**Other info:**

- PostgresSQL is running on Supabase platform
- PostgresSQL version is 14
- My front end is Grafana Cloud. I am trying to get the result table into chart. And I can get the data there only through SQL API calls.

Comment: You can't do that "dynamically" in SQL. You need to do that in your reporting tool or frontend. Search for "pivot" or "crosstab". I wouldn't be surprised if Supabase offered something like that.

Comment: My frontend is Grafana. They get the data to charts through SQL API calls, so my only option is to write this in SQL.

Comment: Grafana (why the Supabase tag then?) should be able to transpose the result of the first query to the desired layout when it _displays_ the data

Comment: I am using both supabase (as my PostgresSQL database) and Grafana as my visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a various list of columns whose number and labels are known only at the runtime is possible but not so obvious with postgres. You need some dynamic sql code.

Here is a full dynamic solution which relies on the creation of a user-defined `composite type` and on the standard functions `jsonb_populate_record` and `jsonb_object_agg` :

First you create the procedure that will create / update the list of ids as a composite type :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE id_list () LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE id_list text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident('value' || id :: text) || ' integer', ',')
    INTO id_list
    FROM your_table ;

  EXECUTE 'DROP TYPE IF EXISTS id_list ' ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE id_list AS (' || COALESCE(id_list, '') || ')' ;
END ;
$$ ;
CALL id_list () ; -- set up the type id_list with the existing list of ids
```

Then you can update the type `id_list ()` by trigger when the list of ids is supposed to be modified in the database :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_table_insert_update()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE id = NEW.id)
  THEN EXECUTE 'ALTER TYPE id_list ADD ATTRIBUTE ' || quote_ident('value' || NEW.id) || ' integer' ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_table_insert_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF id ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION your_table_insert_update() ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_table_delete()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE id = OLD.id)
  THEN EXECUTE 'ALTER TYPE id_list DROP ATTRIBUTE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident('value' || OLD.id) || ' integer' ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN OLD ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_table_delete AFTER DELETE ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION your_table_delete() ;
```

Finally, you should get the expected result with the following query :

```
SELECT time
     , (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: id_list, jsonb_object_agg('value' || id :: text, value))).*
  FROM your_table AS t
 GROUP BY time
 ORDER BY time
```

full test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c0ba446be19b3df93632b743a20fd9bc).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to change the structure of my database. I just want the return query to be in that format :/

Comment: If you don't want to create any new function or a new type in your database then I don't see any postgres solution to your question, go back to a_horse_with_no_name suggestion on the frontend side.